# Building up a matrix dynamically in the xy plane

Tags: c#, algorithm, c++11, matrix

I have to read some data sequentially(from a file) and put the data into a matrix. I don't know the rank of the matrix initially. For example consider the data is plotted on an x, y plane with years on the Y axis and increments in the x axis. At first the data came in for 1990 with 3 increments

```
year increment(1991) increment(1992) increment(1993)
1990  12            25        35
```

Note that I will only know about the increments after reading the data line. So next is 1989 with 4 increments. So it should be

```
year increment(1990) increment(1991) increment(1992) increment(1993)
1989    23             33                    43          53
1990    0              12                    25          35
```

Note that when the new data came in another increment year came in the y axis(1990).As there is no increment year of 1990 for year 1990 this has to be filled with zero or kept it empty, but the

In the end I have to create a matrix. For example

```
year increment(1990) increment(1991) increment(1992) increment(1993) 
1989    23             33                    43          53
1990    0              12                    25          35
1991    0              0                     23          33
```

To build up the matrix, the difficult part is I don't know the years/increments initially, I will only know after reading the entire data. I would like to plot the matrix while reading the data so that I can avoid more than one pass through the data.

The placement of the matrix in the xy axis will be only known after the entire data is processed!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build it as a sparse matrix with `SortedList<int, SortedList<int, int>>`

Answer (score 2):

I quite like the sparse matrix solution, but you could use a version of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array. Dynamic arrays are arrays that you resize when they get too full. Resizing is expensive, but if you increase the size by a constant factor every time you resize the cost of resizing works out so that the total cost is still O(n) if the final size has n elements.

To use dynamic arrays for this, you could create two dynamic arrays for each row, one growing with years larger than those seen so far, and one growing with years smaller than those seen so far (so with years in decreasing order along the array).

Another way to do this would be to create a single area of storage for the matrix, with only the central section used, so there is always space to add entries in any direction. You would then have to check that increasing the size of this storage by a constant factor when you were about to run over the edges would lead to a total cost of at most O(n). I suspect that it would, but the constant factors might not be very good.